# Regex function to display hyperlinks properly on ColdFusion page

Tags: regex, web, hyperlink, coldfusion, html

I am trying to fix an issue with a certain [Coldfusion generated PAGE][1]. Please note, I have little knowledge of ColdFusion and how it works. So if you need more information, please let me know and I will try and track it down.

In the "How to Apply" section of the page there is meant to be included a URL for a certain website. However the page shows only the first part of the URL in clickable hyperlink format. Everything after the `/` is shown as plain text. Can you please suggest a solution ? Here is how the url looks on the page :

> http://example.com/job-vacancies

Please note that the sections are extracted from the database and displayed dynamically in web pages. This image shows how the text looks in the database:

[image: image of text in database]

This is the content of job.cfm:

```
<cfset Application.controller.job()>
```

And this is the content of Application.cfm:

```
<cfapplication name="UK_AC_UEL_JOBSEARCH"
            sessionmanagement="true"
            setclientcookies="false"
            setdomaincookies="false">
<cfscript>
function onRequestStart()
{
    var formKeys = StructKeyList(Form);
    var urlKeys = StructKeyList(URL);
    var key = "";
    var value = "";
    var i = 0;

    // ....
    if (NOT StructKeyExists(Application, "controller"))
    {
        Application.controller = CreateObject("component", "uk.ac.uel.jobsearch.controller.Controller");
    }
    // ....
}
onRequestStart();
```

**Update 1**

I am still in the process of looking for the file that contains what actually renders the page in question. I was able to find Controller.cfc but it doesn't seem like it's directly responsible for rendering the page. After further searching, here is the code I believe renders that section of the page:

```
<div class="display-item last"> 
   <div id="how-to-apply"> 
      <h2>How to apply</h2>              
      <p>#formatWithLinks(Arguments.data.ApplicationProcedure)#</p> 
      <dl> 
          <dt>Closing date</dt> 
          <cfif Arguments.data.HasClosingDate> 
             <dd>#DateFormat(Arguments.data.ClosingDate, "D MMMM YYYY")#</dd> 
          <cfelse> 
             <dd>None: ongoing recruitment</dd> 
          </cfif> 
      </dl> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

I am not sure what to change to tackle this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the code look like that is displaying the URLs?

Comment: There's nothing in the given code that does anything with hyperlinks.

Comment: @abbottmw i wasn't able to find the right file responsible for generating these pages. why is everyone voting down the question ?!

Comment: I expect you're getting downvotes because there's not enough information here for anyone to offer a solution. All we could possibly do is guess.

Comment: What is the CFML code in job.cfm for the "How to apply" section

Comment: *everything after the / is shown as plain text* Look at the view source. That part is being placed *outside* the anchor tags ..

Comment: Thanks @Leigh i have already checked that, but i had no idea what to do to change the way the source is being produced...

Comment: (Edit) All depends on how that cfm page generates the content. Without seeing your code, we can only guess... For example, if the html content for that section is stored in a db table (like with a crm) you need to update the text in the db. Can you show us the CF code used to generate that section?

Comment: @Leigh i have not been able to find that code which is why i posted this question. but what i can tell you is i have access to the database, and each of the sections are stored in different columns in there, i tried adding anchor tags in the database line but that didn't work. would you suggest any other modification for the database text ?

Comment: (Edit) @JayWeb - Well if the actual html is stored in the db, you need to `UPDATE` it to replace the malformed anchor. ie Replace`<a href="http://site/">http://site/</a>job-vacancies` with `<a href="http://site/job-vacancies">http://site/job-vacancies</a>` Unfortunately it is impossible to tell you *how* - without seeing the actual text, or knowing your dbms type. BTW, as mentioned, the lack of details is why the question has received a lot of down votes, see [Ask].

Comment: @Leigh I have attached an image of how the text is stored in the database, there is no html there , i will try and hunt down where the file generating the page would be located, as i have zero knowledge in ColdFusion and how it works i was hoping to get help from here...

Comment: Just a guess by glancing at some of your code. Look for a controller folder under jobsearch folder and then a Controller.cfc in that folder. There should be a job() function in that file.

Comment: Okay, then something else is converting the urls into links. That "something" is probably the cause of the problem. I was just about to suggest the same thing as abbottmw. Look for a file path something like this: uk/ac/uel/jobsearch/controller/Controller.cfc

Comment: Hi guys, thank you very much for the suggestion, i searched for controller folder and it turns out to be in a different directory, however here is the controller.cfc file i found in that folder

Comment: Look at the formatWithLinks() function in that controller.cfc. That should be the function that is converting the URLs to links.

Comment: FYI, not everyone reads the edit history, so it is usually better to "append" than "overwrite". The last few edits removed some important context and details about the app (sample of db text, .cfm script code, etctera). So I did a rollback, and consolidated the relevant edits.

Comment: Just happened to pull this question up again. I see you seemed to have fixed the link problem.  Good job!

Comment: Actually it wasn't me @abbottmw it was my colleague, and i was trying to know from him how he solved it, but all he sent me was that line of code: output = REReplaceNoCase(output,"(\bhttp://[a-z0-9\.\-_:~@##%&/?+=]+)", "<a href=""\1"">\1</a>", "all");

Comment: Yes, so Leigh was right.  It was a regular expression that was matching and building the links.  You could answer your own question with that regular expression your colleague sent you, but I think you need a reputation of 15 or higher to do so. You can also accept your answer as the answer but have to wait 48 hours before you can accept it.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, can someone please tell me where probably that expression should go so i can answer the question with the right solution ? that would be great many thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys just got to the bottom of this, the functions formatWithLinks is the key to solve this, it was found in the view.cfc file as @Leigh suggested ( thank you ) and here is the complete code of the function:

```
<cffunction name="formatWithLinks" output="false" returntype="string">
    <cfargument name="input" />
    <cfscript>
        var output = Arguments.input;
        /*var httpREWithProtocol = "(?x)
                (
                    ((https|http):\/\/)     ## protocol
                    (
                        [a-zA-Z]{1}         
                        ([\w-]+\.)+
                        ([a-zA-Z]{2,})      ## top level domain
                    )                       ## domain name
                    (:[\d]{1,5})?           ## port number
                    ((/?\w+/)+|/?)
                    (\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?
                    ((\?\w+=\w+)?
                    (&\w+=\w+)*)?
                )";*/
        var httpREWithoutProtocol = "(?x)
                (\s)                        ## Space requirement here means this won't match beginning of string
                (
                    (
                        [a-zA-Z]{1}         
                        ([\w-]+\.)+
                        ([a-zA-Z]{2,})      ## top level domain
                    )                       ## domain name
                    (:[\d]{1,5})?           ## port number
                    ((/?\w+/)+|/?)
                    (\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?
                    ((\?\w+=\w+)?
                    (&\w+=\w+)*)?
                )";
        var httpREWithoutProtocolBeginningOfString = "(?x)
                ^                           ## Match string here; I don't like doing it this way, but at least it works
                (
                    (
                        [a-zA-Z]{1}         
                        ([\w-]+\.)+
                        ([a-zA-Z]{2,})      ## top level domain
                    )                       ## domain name
                    (:[\d]{1,5})?           ## port number
                    ((/?\w+/)+|/?)
                    (\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?
                    ((\?\w+=\w+)?
                    (&\w+=\w+)*)?
                )";
        var emailRE = "(?x)
                (
                    [\S]+@                      ## user
                    [a-zA-Z]{1}             
                    ([\w-]+\.)+
                    ([a-zA-Z]{2,})
                )";
        output = REReplace(output, "<[^>]*>", "", "all");
        output = XMLFormat(output);
        //output = REReplace(output, httpREWithProtocol, "<a href=""\1"">\1</a>", "all");
         output = REReplaceNoCase(output,"(\bhttp://[a-z0-9\.\-_:~@##%&/?+=]+)", "<a href=""\1"">\1</a>", "all");
        output = REReplace(output, httpREWithoutProtocol, "\1<a href=""http://\2"">\2</a>", "all");
        output = REReplace(output, httpREWithoutProtocolBeginningOfString, "<a href=""http://\1"">\1</a>", "all");
        output = REReplace(output, emailRE, "<a href=""mailto:\1"">\1</a>", "all");
        return output;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

thank you everyone for trying to help. i greatly appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 0):

The application.cfm is not where your problem is. Have a look in the cfm that actually renders the page. You'll probably find something like this...

```
<a href="http://example.com/">http://example.com/</a>#section#
```

Change that to...

```
<a href="http://example.com/#section#">http://example.com/#section#</a>
```

And you should be golden. Note that everything between the hash tags is a dynamic ColdFusion variable. Your variable name will likely be very different.

Comment: Thank you @Chris, i am still in the process of looking for the file that contains what you suggested, i was able to find Controller.cfc but it doesn't seem like it's directly responsible for rendering the page. i have also found other directories like Template, and Page, i am still looking for clues there...

Comment: Hi @Chris, i have found the bit that renders that sections, can you please have a look ?

Comment: @JayWeb - Keep in mind in that is just an illustration of one way you might create links in CF. The code in your app may be very different. Based on the db screen you posted, I suspect yours *will* be different. My guess is it uses some sort of regular expression to extract url's from text, and convert them to hyperlinks. As abbottmw suggested, the code for that is probably in UDF named `formatWithLinks(...)`. Find that function in your controller.cfc and update your question with that code.

Comment: I agree with Leigh. We need to see the `formatWithLinks()` function. It would also be helpful if you Gabe us a dump of Arguments.data.ApplicationProcedure, which is the input to the function. You can do this by placing the following code above the function call...

   `<CFDUMP var="#Arguments.data.ApplicationProcedure#">`